# Не создаётся текстовый документ

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def napi1():
print('Напиток 1')
n = 1
b = 0
while b > 0:
     open(str(n) +'.txt')
    try:
        n = n + 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
        f = open(str(n)+'no.txt', 'w')
        f.write('1')
        f.close()
        b = 1
```

В чем ошибка, когда запускаю программу "Напиток 1" пишется, а документ не создается. Что делать?. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: в чем состоит задача? ```open(str(n) +'.txt')``` ничего не делает. ```try except ``` в данном случае бесполезен. Поясните задачу пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
def napi1():
    print('Напиток 1')
    n = 1
    while True:
        if not os.path.exists(str(n) + '.txt'):
           f = open(str(n) +'.txt', 'w')
           f.write(n)
           f.close()
           break
        else:
           n += 1
```

Comment: Почти то, надо чтобы можно было создать бесконечно много из. А не только 1 или 2

Answer (score 3):

b равно 0, поэтому цикл `while b>0` не выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

Стоит закрыть файл

> `open(str(n) +'.txt')`

Возможно, поможет 'w+'

И было бы неплохо все-таки увидеть текст ошибки